# readmore.js on an article button and menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

I have a page which has several short articles and a sidenav which scrolls down to an article based on it's id. The articles have been truncated using readmore.js, so they all have a 'Read More' button.

The sidenav link scrolls down to the truncated version.
I would like it to go straight to the full length of the article, but since they are all on the same page I'm not sure how to go on about it.

My code looks like this:

```
<!--sidenav-->

<ul class="sidenav-list navtree-list" id="navtree-0">
  <li >
    <a href="#article1" class="sidenav-item">
      <h2><?php echo $page->header1() ?></h2>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li >
    <a href="#article2" class="sidenav-item">
      <h2><?php echo $page->header2() ?></h2>
    </a>
</li>

<!--articles-->
<div class="container-fluid content-desktop">

<h3 id="article1"><?php echo $page->header1() ?></h3>
  <article data-readmore>
    <?php echo $page->description1()->kirbytext()?> 
  </article>

<h3 id="article2"><?php echo $page->header2() ?></h3>
  <article data-readmore>
    <?php echo $page->description2()->kirbytext()?>
  </article>
```

Any suggestions will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this could normally be solved by using `.readmore('toggle')`, something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidenav-item').click(function() {
      $($(this).attr('href')).next().readmore('toggle');
  })
});
```

This will find the header with the matching id, take the `.next()` element which should be the `<article>`, and expand it with `.readmore('toggle')` once you click the navigation.

**However**, there is [currently a bug](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js/issues/131) in readmore.js preventing this.

If you are comfortable with editing readmore.js yourself, then you can change these sections and replace `_this` with `this` to make it work. It's row `227` and `231` in the non-minimized version of readmore.js.

```
if (! trigger) {
  trigger = $('[aria-controls="' + _this.element.id + '"]')[0];
}

if (! element) {
  element = _this.element;
}
```

Comment: once the underscore is removed, the toggle can be used anywhere, as per the suggestion on http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/ Great advice!

Comment: Good to hear. Please check (✓) the answer as correct if it solved your problem. Cheers!